# Rolio Wi-Fi Adapter 1800Mbps drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, wifi-driver

I recently bought a Rolio Wi-Fi Dongle 1800Mbps: https://rolio.nl/new-wifi-adapter.html

I don't see any instructions about running it on Linux and can't seem to find the chipset its using to install drivers on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using the rtl8852au drivers on Ubuntu: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8852au

As the USB device is mounted as a flash drive instead of a wifi dongle, there are clearer instructions here which you can follow and instead of using the drivers in this repository install the drivers in the link above (rtl8852au) i.e : https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU

Comment: Please post the instructions here